# Custom shorthand Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, shorthand

Is there a way to create custom shorthand's in Visual Studio 2017. 
Just like ctor or prop?

I would like to create a shorthand for unit-tests, to just type in for instance *test* and then having a predefined function to edit like:

```
public void Method_Condition_Expected()
{
   // Arrange

   // Act

   // Assert
}
```

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets and here: https://github.com/mmanela/snippetdesigner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Peter B has suggested for Visual Studio itself you can do it with Snippet Designer (Tools->Code Snippets Manager).

I found out right now, that my installed Tool **ReSharper (2016.3) has an option to create so-called Live-Template's.**

With that, I can create a Template like this:

```
public void $Method$_$Condition$_$Expected$()
{
    // Arrange

    // Act

    // Assert
}
```

The nice part is now, that i can tab through Method,Condition and Expected and overwrite the values.

How to use: Mark a Code-Area such like the code Above in Visual Studio then click on *Resharper->Tools->Create Live Template from Selection->Create and Edit*.

Now wrap code-areas for tabing through with $ for instance like *$Method$* and give a shortcut name such like test.

I hope this helps somebody else as well.

For a closer Comparision between Visual Studio Snippet Manager and Resharper Live Templates see [Difference between Live Template and Visual Studio Snippet](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206010669-Difference-between-Live-Template-and-Visual-Studio-Snippet-)